# xades-t format with java xml signing api

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I would like to use java xml signing api for xades-t signature type. I need to do a canonical transform on signature value node, get a timestamp and insert the result under the object tag.
I can successfully use the api to do regular signing, but I am confused about getting one step further. any pointers are very much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with jXAdES at xades.dev.java.net.

Here you have some sample tests:

https://xades.dev.java.net/source/browse/xades/trunk/jxades/src/main/java/net/java/xades/test/

Hope it helps :)

Regards,
  Ricardo